# Is there a way to color a specific column of a google stacked bar chart when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to set up a site that compares new students from my university from different years.
So far we've set up a pie chart that displays the currently selected year. Now we also want to display a stacked bar chart right next to it, that shows the same numbers overall, but we want it to only highlight the stacked column of the corresponding year from the pie chart. Right now they are all the same color and only highlight one row of the column when hovering over it.

Is it possible to highlight for example the column from year 2017 in different colors when selected, while every other year stays greyscale?

```
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawColumn);
 
function drawColumn(){
    
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Jahr', 'allg. HZB', 'FH-Reife', 'Berufl. Qualifizierte', 'ausl. /Studienkolleg', { role: 'annotation' }],
       ['2013', 35, 37, 0, 2, ''],
       ['2014', 40, 38, 0, 2, ''],
       ['2015', 40, 45, 0, 5, ''],
       ['2016', 46, 36, 0, 3, ''],
       ['2017', 35, 35, 8, 3, ''],
       ['2018', 34, 26, 3, 2, ''],
       ['2019', 43, 31, 2, 6, '']
    ]);

    var options_fullStacked = {
        fontName: "next_artbold",
        fontSize: "30px",
        isStacked: true,
        height: 700,
        width: 900,
        legend: { position: 'none'},
        hAxis: {
            textStyle: {color: 'white'},
            minValue: 0,
        },
        vAxis: {
            textStyle: { color: 'white' },
            minValue: 0,
        },
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        series: {
            0:{color:'#4a86ff'},
            1:{color:'#0d5e98'},
            2:{color:'#0b4c7b'},
            3:{color:'#18365f'}
        }
    };

    var chart_fullStacked = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
        document.getElementById('column'));
    chart_fullStacked.draw(data, options_fullStacked);
}
```

Comment: This sounds totally achievable, but I would need more information to help form a more complete solution. Clarifying your goal:what does it mean to highlight a column "when selected"? Is this hovering or some other interaction? Additionally, is the interaction on the column itself, or on the corresponding year on another chart?

Comment: I have buttons on the top of the page with each year that we have data about. When clicked they display the corresponding pie chart on the left side of the page. On the right side of the page is the stacked bar chart with every information on every year. Right now all of the columns are colored in different shades of blue, but we'd like to implement a way to only show one of the columns in blue (from the one year that's clicked) while the others stay grey (for example).

Comment: Okay, it sounds like there is already state representing which year is selected. Is that state known and available at the time `drawColumn` is called? If so, could you then set the `options_fullStacked` accordingly? (i.e., set the colors in coordination with the selected year)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *style* column role to color an individual bar.

Similar to annotation, you add the color to the data in the data table,
following the value to be given the color.

A value of `null` will allow the series color from the options to be displayed.

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Jahr', 'allg. HZB', {role: 'style'}, 'FH-Reife', {role: 'style'}, 'Berufl. Qualifizierte', {role: 'style'}, 'ausl. /Studienkolleg', {role: 'style'}, {role: 'annotation'}],
   ['2013', 35, '#eeeeee', 37, '#e0e0e0', 0, '#bdbdbd', 2, '#9e9e9e', ''],
   ['2014', 40, '#eeeeee', 38, '#e0e0e0', 0, '#bdbdbd', 2, '#9e9e9e', ''],
   ['2015', 40, '#eeeeee', 45, '#e0e0e0', 0, '#bdbdbd', 5, '#9e9e9e', ''],
   ['2016', 46, '#eeeeee', 36, '#e0e0e0', 0, '#bdbdbd', 3, '#9e9e9e', ''],
   ['2017', 35, null, 35, null, 8, null, 3, null, ''],
   ['2018', 34, '#eeeeee', 26, '#e0e0e0', 3, '#bdbdbd', 2, '#9e9e9e', ''],
   ['2019', 43, '#eeeeee', 31, '#e0e0e0', 2, '#bdbdbd', 6, '#9e9e9e', '']
  ]);
```

See following working snippet.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function (){
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Jahr', 'allg. HZB', {role: 'style'}, 'FH-Reife', {role: 'style'}, 'Berufl. Qualifizierte', {role: 'style'}, 'ausl. /Studienkolleg', {role: 'style'}, {role: 'annotation'}],
   ['2013', 35, '#eeeeee', 37, '#e0e0e0', 0, '#bdbdbd', 2, '#9e9e9e', ''],
   ['2014', 40, '#eeeeee', 38, '#e0e0e0', 0, '#bdbdbd', 2, '#9e9e9e', ''],
   ['2015', 40, '#eeeeee', 45, '#e0e0e0', 0, '#bdbdbd', 5, '#9e9e9e', ''],
   ['2016', 46, '#eeeeee', 36, '#e0e0e0', 0, '#bdbdbd', 3, '#9e9e9e', ''],
   ['2017', 35, null, 35, null, 8, null, 3, null, ''],
   ['2018', 34, '#eeeeee', 26, '#e0e0e0', 3, '#bdbdbd', 2, '#9e9e9e', ''],
   ['2019', 43, '#eeeeee', 31, '#e0e0e0', 2, '#bdbdbd', 6, '#9e9e9e', '']
  ]);

  var options_fullStacked = {
    fontName: "next_artbold",
    fontSize: "30px",
    isStacked: true,
    height: 700,
    width: 900,
    legend: { position: 'none'},
    hAxis: {
      textStyle: {color: 'white'},
      minValue: 0,
    },
    vAxis: {
      textStyle: { color: 'white' },
      minValue: 0,
    },
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    series: {
      0:{color:'#4a86ff'},
      1:{color:'#0d5e98'},
      2:{color:'#0b4c7b'},
      3:{color:'#18365f'}
    }
  };

  var chart_fullStacked = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.getElementById('column')
  );
  chart_fullStacked.draw(data, options_fullStacked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="column"></div>
```